# Как открыть новое окно и оставить смотреть текущее?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Я делаю с помощью `window.open`, но вот при открытии окна пользователя перебрасывает на новое окно, а я хочу оставить его на сайте, а то окошко открыть, как бы незаметно.

Comment: пока в хромике ни один из вариантов не заработал(

Comment: и не заработает. зачем это надо.

Comment: @eicto А жаль) Ну да ладно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работать будет не везде, т.к. это спамерская техника.

```
newWindow=window.open(...);
newWindow.blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
var nwnd = window.open(...);
window.focus();
```

Но некоторые браузеры могут это блокировать..

Если нужно в окне-ребенке еще что-то выполнить и вернуть какие-то результаты, то можно и так:

// Предположим в окне-родителе есть `<div id="descr">`

// Тогда в окне-ребенке добавим скрипт:

```
<script>
function BlaBla(){
        var text=window.opener.document.getElementById('descr');
        text.innerHTML += " 123 ";
        text.focus();
    }    
</script>
```